# asp:LoginStatus automatically log out after some time

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have `asp:LoginStatus` on my master page and in my `login.aspx.cs` file I have logiIn button, which have the selected event handler like.

```
  protected void btLogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int chk = _dbobj.CheckingIfUserExists(tbUserName_login.Text, tbPassword_login.Text);
        if (chk != 0)
        {
            Response.Cookies["UserName"].Value = tbUserName_login.Text.Trim();
            lbUserNameValidation_logIn.Text = "";
            Response.Redirect("Home.aspx", false);

            if (chbRemember_login.Checked)
            {
                Response.Cookies["UserName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
                System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(tbUserName_login.Text, true);
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Cookies["UserName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
                System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(tbUserName_login.Text, false);
            }

        }
        else
           ............
```

When I login without checking remember checkbox, it remembers anyway, and doesn't set loggedout after closing and opening the page.Please help me to solve this..

Answer (score 1):

Use `Page.Session.Timeout` Property for setting session timeout.

Default timeout for .net is 20minites.

Refer this link for  HttpSessionState.Timeout property in .NET

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout.aspx

Hope its helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the Expires property to MinValue makes it a session Cookie

```
cookie.Expires = DateTime.MinValue
```

Expiration session means that cookie lives as long as the browser window with page is open.